# Pyodbc extracts only top three rows

Tags: python, pandas, import, odbc, pyodbc

I am making the transition from R to python and from flat files to relational databases, so this is ugly.

After establishing a connection with my database using pyodbc, i use pandas to extract the tables that i need. I know for a fact that the data table that i need have at least 4000 rows but i keep getting only three rows. pretty sure it's an option that im not specifying correctly, it's just not obvious where i am going wrong.

```
    import pyodbc 
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import *

    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=mydsn')

    hdem = pd.read_sql('select * from mytable', cnxn)
    hdem.shape
```

Where am i going wrong here? 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using, in what environment? What's your DSN definition? Can you retrieve the 4000 rows through any other ODBC client tool in this environment?

Comment: I am using Actual access, running on a MAC, my dsn definition is just a link to the.mdb. how do i make sure that this is not where the problem is?

Comment: [Their product page](http://www.actualtech.com/product_access.php) holds the answer. "Downloaded driver … will only return 3 rows from any query until the driver is registered."

Comment: To follow up, i didnt pay anything when downloading actual access and i can see that this might be some sort of demo...so this might actually be where the problem lies. what are some open source alternatives to drivers?

Comment: No longer (really, never) about programming, this is [not a good question for this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I genuinely thought it was a coding error on my end rather than a problem with my set up. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction, much appreciated!